# Not able to get the page source code after log in through requests

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code for login in the page and getting the source code.

```
import requests
import sys
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''

URL = 'http://coned.com'

def main():
    # Start a session so we can have persistant cookies
    session = requests.session()
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

    # This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
    login_data = {
        'TxtUser': USERNAME,
        'TxtPwd': PASSWORD,
        'submit': 'Sign In',
    }

    # Authenticate
    r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)

    # Try accessing a page that requires you to be logged in
    r = session.get('https://apps1.coned.com/cemyaccount/MemberPages/MyAccounts.aspx?lang=eng')
    resp = opener.open('https://apps1.coned.com/cemyaccount/MemberPages/MyAccounts.aspx?lang=eng')
    print resp
    print r.text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here r.text doesn't work, after log in i need the html code of the page.
can someone help me what to do here?

Comment: Your not using the correct URL. Looking at the web form on the page, the HTML Form is posting to `https://apps1.coned.com/cemyaccount/NonMemberPages/Login.aspx?lang=eng`. Change URL to this endpoint, so you're posting it correctly.

Comment: sorry. i had used the other url also...it doesnt work.:(

Comment: {'submit': 'Sign In', 'TxtUser': '', 'TxtPwd': ''}
<addinfourl at 35439120 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x021CB130>> This is the output i am getting when i am running the above code.

Comment: I have no idea about the requests library, but that second thing, the `addinfourl` is a file-like object, so you need to call `read()` on it.

Comment: HI, i have used resp.read(), but to my surprise i am gettn the code of the home page and not the logged in page.

Comment: i have observed that the log in itself doesn't happen thats y it doesn't give that page details. Cn some one help me plz.

Answer (score 0):

Opening `http://coned.com` in Chrome and opening the Developer Tools pane, I was able to trace my attempted login below. I used `testtesttest` as the username, and `test` as the password.

Headers:

```
Request URL: https://apps2.coned.com/cemyaccount/NonMemberPages/Login.aspx?lang=eng
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Data:

```
TxtUser:testtesttest
UserName:VALUE
UserName:0
TxtPwd:test
UserName2:VALUE
UserName2:0
ctl00$Main$Login1$LoginButton:Sign In
```

Knowing this, you should construct your data dictionary with additional parameters:

```
URL = 'https://apps2.coned.com/cemyaccount/NonMemberPages/Login.aspx?lang=eng'

# This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
login_data = {
    'TxtUser': USERNAME,
    'UserName': 'VALUE',
    'UserName': '0',
    'TxtPwd': PASSWORD,
    'UserName2': 'VALUE',
    'UserName2': '0',
    'ctl00$Main$Login1$LoginButton': 'Sign In',
}

# Authenticate to the login page
r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)

# now, r.text will contain the html results of the page you just requested. In this case, the login page's redirected response.
# Check if the word successful appears in the results...
print filter(lambda x: 'success' in x.lower(), r.text.splitlines())
```

It appears that the site will present you with the login page, which contains one additional piece of HTML if your login was not valid:

```
<span id="ctl00_Main_FailureMsg">Your sign In attempt was not successful. Please try again.  If you have not created your registry information you can register now.</span>
```

Lastly, you should also consider [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/#examples), or [scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/wiki). Both of these tools are very well documented, and built to specifically do what you're after.

Hope that points you in a better direction.

Comment: hi, i am getting the half code of the logged in page and not the full code, here most of the body code is missing, where the table is there

Comment: to add up, the code which i m getting is nothing but the same code of the first page i.e log in page. its something like a master page.